# Uploading large video files (over 3 GB) on a server in the background using URLSession in Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, background, urlsession

I'm currently working on an iOS app using Swift, and I need to implement a feature that allows users to upload large video files (over 3 GB) on a server in the background. To achieve this, I have attempted the following approach:

- Dividing the video file into equal chunks.
- Saving these chunks locally.
- Using URLSession, I fetch and upload each chunk one by one.

Currently, when I put the app in the background, the upload process continues for about a minute, but then it stops uploading. However, when I bring the app back to the foreground, it resumes uploading from where it stopped.

I'm facing the following challenges and would appreciate guidance on potential solutions or improvements:

- How can I ensure that the upload process continues uninterrupted in the background without timing out after a minute?
- Are there any specific considerations or limitations I need to be aware of when using URLSession for uploading large files in the background?
- Are there alternative approaches or libraries that could simplify or optimize this process and provide better background upload capabilities?

Any insights, code snippets, or relevant resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

The execution of the background task is time bounded and again depends on various factors like device performance and battery[energy] saving etc.. So we would not be able to upload or guaranty to upload the file while app being background.

Now to increase the background execution time we can use the "Background Transfer Service" like

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.example.app.background")
let backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://your.server/upload")!)
let task = backgroundSession.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: videoURL)
task.resume()
```

BTW enable the background mode in app target settings.

Comment: I did the same thing but the video uploading in the background was prolonged and paused after some time. Is there any other way to overcome this issue?

Comment: I believe there is no other option!